# How to hide serverside python file from web browser?

Tags: python, apache

Using apache web hosting I launched my first web app today and I noticed that if I put examply.com/example.py in my web browser I can see my python source code with my sql password in it.

How do I prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the file permission

You might want to take a look  here - http://fideloper.com/user-group-permissions-chmod-apache

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Chown your python file with 640 will give a FORBIDDEN in the browser but the server will be able to execute it in PHP for example:

$output = shell_exec("python python-test.py");
echo ($output);